# How do I set a default nick for new Irssi connections?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, irc, irssi

When trying to connect to an IRC server in Irssi, I get the following error:

> root Erroneous Nickname: Reserved for
> services

I don't know how to change the nickname before the connection is established. I'm currently connected to one server, where I have my proper nick, but when trying to connect to another server with `connect irc.foo.com`, which should open **another** connection, it's trying with the nickname *root*.

How do I change this nickname?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to run IRSSI from root.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use Irssi's `-n` option to specify your nick:

```
irssi -n test123
```

Or you can go to the bottom of your `$HOME/.irssi/config` file and in the `settings` section, change the entry "nick".

Comment: An ***alternative*** to changing the configuration file directly (entry "nick") is ***from within an Irssi session***:  `/set nick SomePreferredNickname` and `/save` ([documentation](https://irssi.org/documentation/startup/), near "User information"  (though it is somewhat broken and incomplete)). Similar for entry "user_name": `/set user_name SomePreferredNickname` and `/save`.

Comment: Though changing the global nick name permanently may not be a good answer to the question here(?).

Answer (score 11):

You can use the command:

```
irssi -n nickname1234
```

and to change the default nickname after you are connected

`/SET default_nick = <nick>`, defaults to `user_name`

`/SET alternate_nick = <nick>`, defaults to `<default_nick>`

`/SET user_name = <user>`, defaults to your login name

`/SET real_name = <name>`, taken from `/etc/passwd` by default

Comment: Can you back it up with a reference to documentation?

Comment: `default_nick` is ***way*** out of date. It is just `nick` now. It changed in October 2000 (not a typo - more than 20 years ago). Version [0.7.96](https://irssi.org/NEWS/#v0-7-96) (2000-10-19): *"Changes ... /SET default_nick -> /SET nick"*

Comment: After some consideration (e.g., based on some actual testing), someone might want to update this answer. And specify which version of Irssi was used for testing.

Answer (score -1):

In a terminal, go to the user home directory and `cd` into the *.irssi* directory.

Then

```
touch config
```

Paste in the following:

```json
servers = (
  {
    address = "irc.freenode.net";
    chatnet = "freenode";
    port = "6667";
    use_ssl = "no";
    ssl_verify = "no";
    autoconnect = "yes";
  }
);

chatnets = {
  Freenode = {
    type = "IRC";
    autosendcmd = "/msg nickserv identify yourname yourpass";
  };
};

channels = (
  { name = "#test-channel"; chatnet = "Freenode"; autojoin = "Yes"; }
  { name = "#private-test-channel"; chatnet = "Freenode"; password = "yourpass"; autojoin = "Yes"; }
);

settings = {
  core = { real_name = "real name"; user_name = "user name"; nick = "yourusername"; };
  "fe-text" = { actlist_sort = "refnum"; term_force_colors = "yes"; scrollback_time = "7day "; };
  "fe-common/core" = { theme = "default"; };
};
```

Comment: There is no reason to not use TLS, copy pasting settings without understanding them is a generally bad idea. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Some of those settings may already exist in the `~/.irssi/config` file. What is the consequence of duplicate entries?

Comment: What is the purpose of `touch config`? Is it really necessary? Doesn't the `~/.irssi/config` file already exist if Irssi has been run and Irssi doesn't care about the modification date? (Not rhetorical questions.)